# how to display text in div dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched on the forum and saw posts about changing text dynamically upon click. But in my case I want to change the display dynamically when loading the page from beginning. I already have a function that figure out what I should display:

```
function phone()
{
//code here
return phone;
}
```

And my question is how to display the returned phone number in the div below to replace the 1.888.888.8888 part. Can anyone offer some insights? Thank you!

```
<div class="add-info">
<span class="rightfloat">Order online <span class="red">or call 1.888.888.8888</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would change the HTML to add another `<span>` tag around the phone number and give that span tag an `id` attribute in order to access it easily (broke it up on separate lines to reduce scrolling):

```
<div class="add-info">
    <span class="rightfloat">
        Order online <span class="red">
            or call <span id="contact-number"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then after the page loads update the `span` with whatever value you want:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('contact-number').innerHTML = PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE;
}
```

In JQuery, it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contact-number').html(PHONE_NUMBER_VALUE);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Talemyn! But I'm not so sure what you meant by "after the page loads". I want the number to display when the user first see the page, not after the page has loaded. Sorry if it's a silly question... I'm really new to js.

Comment: Well, the page has to finish loading (and the DOM structure finish building) before the JS can act on it.  However, this should be REALLY fast, to the point that it will seem to the user like it loaded with the number in it to begin with.  The only way that this would likely be an issue would be if something slowed the page load down so much that you would see this section before the rest of the page loaded.  If that's a concern, you could hide the `add-info` section (or even the entire `<body>`) by default and then unhide it immediately after updating the number.

Answer (score 4):

You can,

```
<body onload="phone();">
    <div class="add-info">
        <span class="rightfloat">Order online <span class="red">or call
            <span id="phone"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

And set the value when the function runs;

```
function phone() {
    document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = "1.888.888.8888";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Can you say a few more words about what onload="phone()" does here? I just want to display the right phone number on the page as soon as user sees it, with out any delay.

Comment: Its an event that fires when the body loads (i.e. all of its HTML is available for use) it ensures that you do not try to manipulate elements before the browser knows they exist.

Comment: I have a lot of div in the body. Do I add <body onload="phone();"> to the overall body? don't know if that will affect other div that doesn't need phone()...

Comment: No, the function `phone()` runs one time when the body and its contents loads. As `phone()` specifically updates the element with `id="phone"` (of which there should only ever by one) it wont change any other content on the page

Comment: Alex, sorry for bothering you so much. Can you please suggest a good book or website for me to learn javascript? I feel I really need to learn all the concepts systematically. I have some java programming experience but don't know anything about javascript. And I feel guessing and trail and error are not the most efficient way to learn.

Comment: Crockford is a good bet http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112705/javascript-is-this-a-grey-area-for-anyone-else / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988421/javascript-books-for-better-understanding-with-concrete-examples

Comment: Thank Alex! I actually implement the code, but it mess up the whole page... the old javascript function that was already there stopped working... really can't figure out why. Guess I have to learn js from beginning... :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning 'phone', why don't you put an id on your span and just use 
`document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML = phone` 
in your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Call you code from the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the number into additional `<span>` tag with its own id and change content of it with js...

```
document.getElementById('id_of_span').innerText = 'new number';
```

Comment: `innerText` is not compatible with firefox, `innerHTML` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    function phone(number) {
        var redText = document.getElementByClassname("red")[0];
        redText.innerHTML = "or call " + number;
    }
</script>
```

To call it you can use clicks, loads or anything else. For example

```
<script>
    window.onload = phone('NEW NUMBER HERE');
</script>
```

Bear in mind that adding another window onload function later will displace this one, so you would either need to add to it, or use a double delegate function, but that's another story...